# OpenLayers geolocation change:position event fires too often

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers-3

I'm using Openlayers 3. I created a geolocation object and registered as a listener to the change:position event. I expected that the event fires only, if the location is changed. But this is not the case. It fires every 10 seconds, the location is every time exactly the same.

I tested this on Android.

What's the reason for this behaviour? Can this be changed in any way?

Comment: Are the coordinates exactly the same when the event is triggered? Maybe it is also triggered due to measurement inaccuracies / errors?

Comment: @Lars: Yes the coordinates were exactly the same. Interesting is that it fired exactly every 10 seconds. So for me it looks like that event is just triggered by the time elapsed and not by a change of the location.